# docker container status is restarting and port is empty from the next js application

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, next.js13, nextjs-image

I tried deploying the new next js application and deployed it to a docker container [link here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/deploying#docker-image) as I followed the document. When deployed my application(docker container) faced an issue. docker build successfully. but once running the application status restarted and the ports were empty.

```
Docker file
-----------

FROM node:18-alpine AS base

# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM base AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies based on the preferred package manager
COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
RUN \
  if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn --frozen-lockfile; \
  elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm ci; \
  elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then yarn global add pnpm && pnpm i --frozen-lockfile; \
  else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
  fi


# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
# Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during the build.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN yarn build

# If using npm comment out above and use below instead
# RUN npm run build

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during runtime.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public

# Set the correct permission for prerender cache
RUN mkdir .next
RUN chown nextjs:nodejs .next

# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000
# set hostname to localhost
ENV HOSTNAME "0.0.0.0"

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

### docker-compose.yaml

```
image: username/subdomain:v1
    container_name: container1
    ports:
      - 0.0.0.0:3000:3000
    restart: always
    networks:
      - net
```

used two commands to start the next js application

```
docker compose up -d
```

```
docker run -d -P 3000:3000 --name containerId username/subdomain:v1
```

but facing the issue of restarting for the I try tostatus column and empty column for ports

[image]

Can anyone help me out with this issue?